# Why use $query instead of direct query string in mysql_query("string")?

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone please explain to me why the following doesn't work:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'");
```

Whereas the following does work:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Is that even true? The function calls are the same, but the second has a `<br>` in the code which would make it invalid. So if any of these won't work, it's the second.

Comment: @GolezTrol That `<br>` was there because before I edited he had no code boxes. So first I edited and added the code boxes but forgot to remove the `<br>` so I edited again and removed the `<br>`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still just as curious as last night. No answer that really explains why this error occured - and not just a random one either.

Comment: Ok, in that case, the two pieces of code *should* do the same thing, unless the value of `$id` is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both should work exactly the same.

Try this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = '{$id}'");
```

That always works for me. But putting it in a variable makes it easier to work with sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between the two.  Both are vulnerable to SQL injection, as well.  You should use prepared statements or `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: I've already done this. The code pasted above is just a snippet. Thing is, I know there should be no difference, but it actually was the problem.

Comment: There are better ways then using mysql_real_escape_string. Besides, who says `$id` isn't already escaped or even int-casted?

Comment: I mentioned prepared statements first.  `$id` could already be escaped, though it's best to do it at the last minute to avoid such confusion.  But if it's int-casted, there shouldn't be quotes.

Answer (score 2):

There's no functional different between the two, but storing the query in a separate variable makes it easier to debug the statement that's produced.

e.g.

```
$sql = "...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "Query failed: ", $sql, mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: that's the wrong way to do it, you should encapsulate the mysql_query calls.

Comment: in a function, in a member method, or in a ORM layer... I would like to scream when I see bare mysql_query calls.

Comment: That's an opinion. It's neither right nor wrong. Some people prefer "bare metal". And when you know what you're doing, there's nothing wrong with bare metal.

Comment: it's just plain wrong. and that's not an opinion. want to check if it failed? would like to log the created queries? want to measure the elapsed time for each of them? if it's not encapsulated you have to do it at many-many places. give me just **one** good reason not to encapsulate those calls! (no, performance isn't. an extra function call is orders of magnitudes faster than a db query)

Comment: Again, that's opinion. For every reason you can come up with, someone else'll have a counter. Go ahead and argue all you want, I'm not going to.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, this is cutted out of a method already. Just curious of the sql-part. It actually didn't work, just like I described earlier. That's why I'm curious. I know it's supposed to.

Comment: @yi_H 1. Someone who has to ask this question, may not yet be up to implementing ORM layers. And please don't argue that you did in your first PHP app. 2. This answer is just an example on catching the result of the function and showing the query value in a 'debugger'. 3. ORM sucks. You'd rather write business objects which don't necessarily have to map directly to tables, but instead can write logical entities no matter how and where they're stored. 4. If you propagate ORM the way you do, at least you should have suggested prepared statements using mysqli or rather PDO. 5. Oops, out of space.

Comment: @GolezTrol: in my very first app I wrote a function called `Q` which called mysql_query. I was a beginner and created a lot of invalid queries, parts of the code weren't working... so it felt logical (DRY principle) to enccapsulate the call so I can write a huge bold red message that the query failed. Of course at that time I didn't know what DRY or encapsulation is. about ORM: a proper ORM provides you an API that hides from you the fact that it is actually storing values in a relational database so you *can* replace the specific classes if you feel SQL is not right choice for them.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect online examples just started using a separate `$query` variable, and people copied it without really thinking about it, and then more examples implemented that, and now tons of people do it without necessarily knowing why. C'est la vie.